# Copying a section from Google Docs to another Doc using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've successfully used this code to copy the entirety of one doc into another doc:

```js
const newestFile = DocumentApp.openById("ID").getBody();
const archive = DocumentApp.openById("ID").getBody();
let index = 12;
  let el, type;
  for (let i = 0; i < newestFile.getNumChildren(); i++){
    el = newestFile.getChild(i);
    type = el.getType();
    switch (type){
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        archive.insertParagraph(index,el.copy());
        index++;
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        archive.insertListItem(index,el.copy());
        index++;
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        archive.insertTable(index,el.copy());
        index++;
        break;
    }
  }
```

However, I now need to copy a *portion* of a doc into another doc, and I can't figure it out. If I knew how to get the body index of any element I could do it the same way, but I don't know if that's even possible. The text I need to copy out will always be preceded by a specific text ("Current Week") and end immediatly before a specific text ("ARCHIVE").

Comment: Please provide a test docs file with sample data for replication. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Typically a body is broken down into paragraphs.  If your "section" spans paragraphs you could check if the text of a paragraph contains "Current Week" until you get to "ARCHIVE" and pull that out and copy to another doc.  If you need an example let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

Here is a simple example of how to copy between certain text.  I've only covered paragraphs and tables but any other type of Element can be handled.

**Test Document**

[image]

**Script**

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let count = body.getNumChildren();
    doc = DocumentApp.create("dummy");
    let copy = doc.getBody();
    let start = false;

    for( let i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
      let child = body.getChild(i);
      if( child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
        if( child.asParagraph().findText("Current Week") ) start = true; 
        if( start ) copy.appendParagraph(child.asParagraph().copy());
        if( child.asParagraph().findText("ARCHIVE") ) break;
      }
      else if( child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ) {
        if( start ) copy.appendTable(child.asTable().copy());
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in myFunction - "+err)
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChild(Integer)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body

Comment: That makes sense! I was hoping there was a way to just find the body index of a particular element, but that works, too!
Do you know why .copy() isn't transferring the formatting correctly? My Heading 1 element is of a particular font, size, and weight, but those formatting elements aren't translating to the new document.

Comment: I too was hoping there would be some kind of index between the beginning of a section to the end and the just copy that block to another doc.  But unfortunately there isn't.  A RangeElement only works within a paragraph.